# How can I make a command execute at startup?

Tags: bash, scripts, startup

I wanted to remap the keys for my page up and page down number pad so that they would actually act like the real page up and page down.  I used the xmodmap successfully following the directions based on the [how-do-i-remap-certain-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) help (plus some a tweak that I realized on my own).

**I would like to make those two commands execute every time I start the computer:**

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 89 = Next KP_3 Next KP_3"
xmodmap -e "keycode 81 = Prior KP_9 Prior KP_9"
```

Sure, I can see that the proper way to remap the keys would be to create `xinitrc` and `Xmodmap` files, but I thought it would be a good time to learn how to make something happen at startup instead.  Also, I thought this would be easier to maintain since I would only have to keep track of the startup scripts rather than remember the xmodmap files.

Based on the instructions in [how to make a command execute at start-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46953/how-can-i-add-commands-to-startup-requiring-admin-privileges?lq=1) I thought I could add the commands to my `/etc/rc.local` file, but that's clearly not working.

Also, based on the directions in the [bash startup guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files), I tried adding the commands to `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.  This also didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49793/script-at-startup?rq=1)

Comment: I don't see why you suggested that I read that answer.

Comment: Because that's how you're supposed to add whatever to the start-up by using Startup applications, either you add a script or the command themselves.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know how to find the startup applications application at first, that does work if I add /etc/rc.local to the startup applications.  But, why didn't that run at startup by default?  (I see now that the the bash config files probably only apply to terminal windows... so now that part makes sense. I thought they ran at system startup)