# How can we setup Startup tasks

Tags: 13.10, startup, startup-applications, task-management

In Windows we can add applications/batch scripts to open automatically on startup. Is there something similar in Ubuntu, or Linux in general?

Comment: Thank you both kiloseven and wilf I am not able to mark both as Answers. I marked 1.

Comment: My answer wasn't very good :D - I upvoted @kiloseven's anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321)

Comment: Since the user mentioned `Linux in general`, I don't think the link above is the universal answer they wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup tasks to run on login, use `gnome-session-properties`. This means you can add programs to run when you login to user account on your machine.
[image]

You can configure it like this - just add the command you want to run in the command box:
[image: config]

Very long answer on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/178596)

To get things to run when the computer boots, use `rc.local`:

You can edit it with `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`, or `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`.

Makes sure it has this line at the start of the file:

```
 #!/bin/sh -e
```

Below that, you can place commands that will run as root when you start the computer.

Also make sure it has this line at the end:

```
exit 0
```

More on that [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the universal, multi-distro solution.

Create a script (don't forget to start with the [shabang!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) and place that script in

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

After rebooting, the script will launch, and you can also find it in Startup Applications (see the last screenshot [in this link for an illustration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49793/script-at-startup)).

This complies with the [XDG Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) and works with [any compliant distro of Linux](https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/).

Comment: It should be noted that this is for **all users**. If you only want it to be your user, see [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321) or wilf's asnwer.